# Track amount of data application and a device file are exchanging

Tags: files, pipe

Is it possible to track how much data is going into a device file and an application as a third person?

**Background**

A web server is communicating with a device `/dev/ttyACM0`. The server offers a HTTP API for accessing the device. I've been experiencing that the device represented by the `/dev/ttyACM0` has been overloaded (I can see physically see the device restarting). Because of that I would like to get a rough overview on how much data is being sent into `/dev/ttyACM0` from the HTTP server application.

Comment: You could probably use `socat` to connect a pty/tty in between the web server and the actual serial port, then monitor that pty connection.  Can't really make an answer, because I've never tried